# Remove 0 from object using Math.min.apply

Tags: javascript

With the following JavaScript object, I am getting the min price using

```
var min = Math.min.apply( null, response.map((v) => v.room.price));
```

**Response**

```
let response = [
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 217,
      "available": true
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 302,
      "available": true,
    }
  },
  {
    "room": {
      "price": 0,
      "available": false,
    }
  }
];
```

Currently when I run this, I will `0` as the min price but I don't `0`, I want `217`. How do I remove `0` dynmically?

**I have tried:**

```
var min = Math.min.apply( null, response.map((v) => v.room.price > 0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out non-zero numbers.

```
var min = Math.min.apply( null, response.map((v) => v.room.price).filter(Boolean));
```

---

Or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method instead.

```
var min = response.reduce((a, b) => (a.room.price < a.room.price && a.room.price != 0) ? a : b).room.price;
```

Comment: if you're going to use arrow functions and everything, then also use `Math.min.(...`.